# Storybook error: Missing "./preview.js" specifier in "@storybook/react" package

Tags: vite, storybook, react-typescript

I am trying to integrate together storybook, react, vite and TS.

When trying to run storybook, I have the following error in the console:

```
Missing "./preview.js" specifier in "@storybook/react" package
4:02:06 PM [vite] Internal server error: Missing "./preview.js" specifier in "@storybook/react" package
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
```

My stories are well discovered and listed, but the preview is showing an infinite circle loader.

I tried to create a new web app in react/ts with vite.

`yarn create vite my-app --template react-ts`

Then I integrated storybook by simply running:

`npx sb init --builder @storybook/builder-vite`

I have the following dev dependencies:

```
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.0.17",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",

    "storybook": "^7.0.17",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
```

I haven't found any solution, nowhere. Does Anyone here encountered the same?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after some digging found a GitHub issue for it that confirms there is a bug in the package: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/23338 .

Upgrade vite to v4.4.1, that solved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi @abusse29, thanks for your solution. It solved my problem. Just upgraded to 4.4.1.

Comment: removing node_modules & .lock files & re-installing the packages fixed the issue for me.